# Invalid Cell Coordinate phpExcel while reading xlsm files

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am just trying to read the custom properties of the xlsm sheet.

Using 'Excel2007' reader object. While running I am getting the following error stack trace.

Can anyone tell what's wrong?

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate IDc3' in C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:546 Stack trace: #0 C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\excel\Classes\PHPExcel\ReferenceHelper.php(884): PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('IDc3') #1 C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\excel\Classes\PHPExcel\ReferenceHelper.php(794): PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper->_updateSingleCellReference('IDc3', 'A1', 0, 1) #2 C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\excel\Classes\PHPExcel\ReferenceHelper.php(739): PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper->updateCellReference('IDc3', 'A1', 0, 1) #3 C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php(306): PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper->updateFormulaReferences('=IF(IDc3Y=0,"No...', 'A1', 0, 1) #4 C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php(861): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->_castToFormula(Object(SimpleXMLElement), 'F15', 'f', '=', 'Not Attempted', Array, '_castToString') #5 C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\excel\Documentation\Examples\Reading Work in C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 546

Is there some problem in the workbook? Please guide.

Comment: Without details of the broadsheet file that's causing this error it's almost impossible to say what's causing it. Is it possible for you to upload the file to the codeplex site?

Comment: Hi Mark... i cannot share the workbook. It's just that 'ID' is one of the sheets in workbook.

Comment: Check that any references used in the spreadsheet use a ! Separator between worksheet id and cell reference (eg ID!C3 for cell C3 in worksheet ID)